# how to update httpd conf file using ansible

Tags: centos, ansible

I would like to update http log format using Ansible.

Current config looks like:

```
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
```

Need to update to the following:

```
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t %D %X \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\" %I %O" combined
```

Tried using the `replace` module. But it didn't edit the file...

```
---
- name: test
  hosts: testServer
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:
  - name: configure httpd
    replace:
      path: /tmp/httpd.conf
      regexp: 'LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined'
      replace: 'LogFormat "%h %l %u %t %D %X \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\" %I %O" combined'
```

Note: I have copied `httpd.conf` to `/tmp` for testing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

End up with below playbook

```
---
- name: test
  hosts: testServer
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:
  - name: configure httpd
    replace:
      path: /tmp/httpd.conf
      regexp: '^LogFormat.*combined$'
      replace: 'LogFormat "%h %l %u %t %D %X \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\" %I %O" combined'
```

plz, let me know if we can do with better regex.

Comment: I'd suggest using `lineinfile` instead of `replace`.